# Pointer passed by reference and local function variable lifetime

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

void swapInt(int*& a, int*& b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    // *b = temp;   // the intended way

    std::cout << "&temp: " << &temp << '\n';
    std::cout << "b before change: " << b << '\n';

    b = &temp;                                      // this also works? UB or not?

    std::cout << "b after change: "<< b << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = 10;

    int* p = &a;
    int* q = &b;

    std::cout << "q before call: " << q << '\n';

    swapInt(p, q);

    std::cout << *p << ' ' << *q << '\n';       // q is pointing to temp here

    std::cout << "q after call: " << q << '\n'; // q is pointing to temp here


    std::cout <<"\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
q before call: 00D1F87C
&temp: 00D1F860
b before change: 00D1F87C
b after change: 00D1F860
10 4
q after call: 00D1F860
```

What is unclear to me is what exactly is happening:

1) Is this UB and just appears to work because the memory is not altered
OR
2) Is there some rule that prevents the local variable to be destroyed if assigned to a pointer passed by reference (like when an automatic temporary's lifetime is bound to a reference when returned by value)?

Comment: It's option #1.

Comment: there's no reference counter in C++. So it's UB.

Comment: Essentially [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) this is your issue but instead of returning by return value you are returning by parameter.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes I've read that and similar questions, just wasn't sure if it's the same issue or one of those fringe "awesome" exceptions from the rules. Hence better to ask.

Comment: There are no exceptions to the rule that you cannot access a variable after its lifetime ends.

Comment: @NathanOliver Was thinking more about maybe the lifetime of the variable is extended for whatever reasons behind the curtains.